# How to insert caption for multiple figures side by side

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, caption

I'm working on a Word document, and I would like to put two figures side by side, using the same figure number (e.g. Figure 1) but with a letter for each figure (1a and 1b).

What is the cleanest way to do this? I could just add text after the caption and the cross-references, but it would be better if there was a hierarchical way, so that for instance in the list of figures I can see them separately but with indentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a drawing canvas (it's in menu `Insert -> Shapes -> New drawing canvas` (it is at the very bottom)), put both your drawings in it and put your caption for the canvas.

Comment: Is it a windows-only feature?

Comment: @eiennohito but again this would lead to one caption underneath the group inside the canvas, is there any way to insert two captions separately for two side by side figure inside the canvas, and even worse, when the caption of each is very long, more than full line,, Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest that you use a borderless table with two columns and two rows. You can paste your two pictures in the two cells of the first row, and then add the corresponding a) and b) captions below each figure on the next row.

Comment: Sounds like the HTML table approach to fake proper layouting tools but many thanks to you since it does the trick nicely!

Answer (score 2):

When I want to do this, I just use my snipping tool to create a new image that includes both pictures in one image.